# Open source server side for Android's calendar

Tags: open-source, calendar, server

My Android Samsung phone, comes with an application called "calendar", which evidently, permits events recording.  On the first attempt to add an event, it asks for the backend counterpart.  You can choose "Server", "LDAP", "Microsoft Exchange", (and some other choices).

As I want to host the backend side myself on a shared hosting, what can I use?

Comment: What is the exact package name (some.namespace.like.this) of that particular calendar application?

Comment: What information is retrieved from the "Server"? For instance LDAP usually does not contain events, only users/groups.

Comment: Apliction Manager says:  Calendar  4.1.2- S7390LUBUANJ1  Thanks Nicolas

Comment: At the point to add an event is says **no calendars**, Before you can add an event you must add at least one Calendar account to your device. Touch Add Account to add an account  ....  then I can selecct server side account manager, the options that remains to me are LDAP, Microsoft Exchange and Sever. Other options were disabled/removed by me some time ago, they were Google Account and others. "Server" option sounds like a generic one. If I choose it, it has only four configuration settings: profile name, sync category, sync type ans sync server, which starts as http:// and you fill the rest.

Comment: Could you please post some screenshot? Some people might recognize the app.